# How to install software-properties-gtk package in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Whenever I tried to install new package,

"The package software-properties-gtk needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

this error is occurred.

When i ran this command:   "sudo apt-get install celery"

following error is occurred:

"Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: The package software-properties-gtk needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Comment: First of all this issue has nothing to do with python tag, you should look for it at [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). second try to mention command you executed and error directly instead of image. advice: as you have used transparency in terminal your personal information is appearing in image

Comment: @Gahan, Do you have any idea how to solve this error?